# count by field in awk before pipe symbol

Tags: awk

I am trying to count the unique entries in `$2` in a file before the `|`:

**file**

```
chr11:101323676-101323847   TRPC6|gc=39.2   143.1
chr11:101324359-101324478   TRPC6|gc=38.7   146.4
chr11:101325731-101325850   TRPC6|gc=32.8   84.5
chr11:101341904-101342127   TRPC6|gc=43.5   197.9
chr12:5153304-5155165   KCNA5|gc=65.1   633.7
chr12:52306230-52306349 ACVRL1|gc=58.8  152.4
chr12:52306868-52307149 ACVRL1|gc=66.5  309.6
chr12:52307328-52307569 ACVRL1|gc=66.8  305.9
chr12:52307743-52307872 ACVRL1|gc=64.3  267.1
```

**desired output**

3

Tried:

```
awk '{sub(/:.*/,"",$2)} !seen[$2]++{unq++} END{print unq}' file.txt
```

Currently, I am getting a very different number and think it is necause I need to split on the `|` but not sure the correct way to do so.  Thank you :).

Comment: add another sub, ie `sub/\|.*$/, "", $0)`. Good luck.

Comment: hm.. I also think you need to debug your steps. Adding `print #dbg: $2 before="$2` and `print "#dbg $2 after=" $2` at the appropriate locations should help. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there. You simply need to replace `:` by `\|` in the regex used in `sub()`:

```
awk '{sub(/\|.*/,"",$2)}!seen[$2]++{c++}END{print c}' file
```

You can also play with the delimiter like this:

```
awk -F'[|]| +' '!seen[$2]++{c++}END{print c}' file
```

I'm using either `|` or *one or more* spaces as the delimiter. This makes it possible to access the part of interest as `$2`.

The remaining part follows the same logic as the example in your question: We use `$2` as index in the lookup table `seen` and check if this index has appeared before. If not, we increment the counter `c` and at the end we print `c`.

Answer (score 4):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{split($2,a,"|"); c[a[1]]} 
    END{for(k in c) count++; print count}' file

3
```

or shorter version

```
$ awk '{split($2,a,"|"); if(!c[a[1]]++) count++} 
    END{print count}' file
```

shortest

```
$ awk 'split($2,a,"|") && !c[a[1]]++{u++} END{print u}' file
```